# A product of curves is a minimal surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ and $B$ be smooth projective curves of genus 1 and $g$, respectively. Set $X=E \times B$. Then, the second projection $f: X \rightarrow B$ is a genus 1 fibration and $\omega_X \cong f^* \omega_B$.

How does one see that $X$ is a minimal surface and that $X$ is of type (A), (B), or (C), if $g(B)=0$, $1$ , or $\geq 2$, respectively.

Where the following are the types:

(A) $K_X$ is not nef.

(B) $K_X \equiv 0$.

(C) $K_X$ is nef, $K_X \not \equiv 0$ and $K_X^2=0$.

Comment: First step is to find the canonical sheaf of the product. Also, what definition of minimal surface are you working with e.g. it is minimal if there exists no $(-1)$-curves?

Comment: Yes, this is my definition. I also know that the canonical sheaf of the product is the tensor product of the pull back of the canonical sheaf on each factor, but I am unsure as to how to use this, especially to see minimality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer. Hopefully there are no silly mistakes as written. Note that $K_X\cong \pi_1^*O_E\otimes \pi_2^*K_B\cong \pi_2^*K_B$ where $\pi_i$ are the two projections from $E\times B$.

(A) In this case, $K_B\cong \pi_2^* O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)$. Take the canonical divisor $K_X$, observe it has negative degree along any fibre of the map $\pi_1:X\to E$, and so cannot be nef.

(B) Since $K_B\cong O_B$ due to $B$ being an elliptic curve, the canonical divisor $K_X$ is trivial so it is certainly nef. Alternatively, $X$ is an abelian surface and canonical bundles on abelian varieties are always trivial.

(C) This is trickier $K_X\cong \pi_2^*K_B$ requires we use the higher genus assumption in a particular way: $\pi_2^*K_B$ is an effective divisor. The reason is that $K_B$ itself is an effective divisor: by Riemann-Roch $H^0(B,K_B)-1=2g(B)-2+1-g(B)=g(B)-1$ so that $H^0(B,K_B)\neq 0$. Then, the pullback of an effective divisor under $E\times B\to B$ is effective. Furthermore, it cannot be numerically trivial. By effectiveness of $K_X$, if $K_X^2\geq 0$, then $K_X$ is nef.

So we show $K_X^2\geq 0$ and $K_X\not\equiv 0$. The first fact follows from a standard result: Hartshorne Exercise V.1.5. $K_X^2= 8(g(E)-1)(g(B)-1)=0$. So $K_X\not\equiv 0$ is all that is left.

Probably the easiest way to show that $K_X\not\equiv 0$ is to show that it intersects some curve nontrivially. Consider $\{O\}\times B\subseteq X$ and then $K_X.(\{O\}\times B)$ intersects at some point in $\{O\}\times B$.

Now to prove minimality, we need to show there are no $(-1)$-curves.

(A) is the case of $E\times \mathbb{P}^1$ which is a ruled surface over $E$. These are always minimal e.g. Hartshorne V.2 computes $\operatorname{Num}(X)=\mathbb{Z}C_0\oplus\mathbb{Z}f$ where $C_0$ is a section $\mathbb{P}^1\to X$ and $f$ is the numerical class of the fibre and $C_0.f=1$, $f^2=0$, and $C_0^2=0$. The fact that $C_0^2=0$ comes from the fact that $E\times \mathbb{P}^1$ is the $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle associated to the rank $2$-vector bundle $O_E\oplus O_E$.

(B) and (C) here I will cheat a little and use the following fact: if the canonical bundle is nef, then there are no $(-1)$-curves.  One way to see this is that if $C$ is a $(-1)$-curve, then applying the adjunction formula to $C$ implies $2g(C)-2=C.(C+K)$ and since $g(C)=0$ we get $-2=C.(C+K)$ and so $C.K=-1$. Since $K_X$ is nef due to $K_X$ being trivial, this cannot be and there are no $(-1)$-curves. This also proves (c) is minimal.

Comment: in case (C), wouldn't the fact $K_X$ is effective and contained in fibers be enough to show that it is nef and that $K_X^2 = 0$

Comment: Isn't (A) the case of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times E^1$? where $E^1$ is an elliptic curve... so i'm not quite sure how to show that this is a minimal surface.

Comment: @PaulImmanuel Oops, I had the typo in case $A$. Let me fix this. Also for (c), I think the self-intersection of the fibre being $0$ is enough too. Didn't think to write it that way.